# How to make library globally available in Composition API?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I need the `vuex store` basically in every component and want to know if there is a way to omit:

```
import {useStore} from "vuex";

const store = useStore()
```

from all components and instead import it automatically so I could just use it like so:

```
store.state.image = "..."
```

Right now I've imported the `store` in a seperate **`store.js`** file:

```
import {createStore} from "vuex";

const store = createStore({
    state() {
        return {
            image: sessionStorage.image || ""
        }
    }
})

export default store
```

and register it in **`app.js`**:

```
require('./bootstrap');

import {createApp} from 'vue';
import app from "../vue/app";
import store from "./store";

createApp(app)
    .use(store)
    .mount("#app");
```

I've tried this:

```
createApp(app)
    .component('store', store)
    .mount("#app");
```

but it says that `store object` of `type any` can't be registered as `component`.

Comment: This is a mistake, `component('store', store)`. You can't use it as component because it's not component. You can import `store` directly.

Comment: @EstusFlask yes but I'm looking for a way to make it usable without `import`

Comment: There won't be a good way. Dependencies are supposed to be explicitly imported in modern JS. A thing you can do is to not write `useStore` part and import `store` directly.This is not a problem because IDEs can handle auto-imports and the use of `store` doesn't require to type `import` .

Comment: Btw ctx.root.$store may be available but its use is discouraged, I believe it's untyped in case you use TS.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you're using `useStore`, then you must have used `setup`.

```js
export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
        const store = useStore();
    }
})
```

This statement only applies to `setup`. Because there is no `this` in `setup`, this is an alternative way to get `store`.

As you say, you want to use it globally. But as long as at `setup`, you must to be import this method. Even if you want to use a global method.

To access the store within the `setup` hook, you can call the `useStore` function. This is the equivalent of retrieving `this.$store` within a component using the Option API. [[vuex composition api guide]](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api.html)

So you can use `this.$store.state.image` in any other where like `vue2`.

[the simplest store](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/#the-simplest-store)

Comment: There's no `this` component instance in composition api. The suggestion is not use composition API and use obsolete options API, right?

Comment: @EstusFlask yes, you are right. So he has to import `useStore` methods every time. Unless he uses `Option API`.

Comment: `Composition API` has too many benefits to not use it. I hope they implement some way in the future.

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov Yes, I agree with you. But I don't think it's easy to solve at this stage. I even think the return syntax in `setup` unfriendly. There are also many inconveniences tousing `<script setup>`. finally, your problem looks more like an issue, it requires an entirely new solution

Comment: @jeremyjone Out of curiosity, what would be a downside of using script setup?

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov I think it just avoids `return syntax`. Inside, everything is exposed. Also, if you need some other settings, such as settings the name of the component, need to write a separate `<script>` tag. In the meantime, you have to define `defineProps` and `defineEmit` separately, which are params to `setup` function.

Comment: @jeremyjone Yes, I've been working without those things but I'm a beginner at best. So far it worked out for me.